# Converting to high bases

Tags: c++, radix

I'm writing a program in C++ where you enter a number and it lists all the bases in which that number is a palindrome. What I'm stuck on is what to do for higher bases though, for example:

```
Converting 170 to base 90,

170 % 90 = 1 R 80
1 % 90 = 0 R 1
```

So since the Remainder 80 is above the letter Z which would be 35, what do you do?

I cant seem to find any converters that go up to bases this high to test out what should happen, so if anyone could point me to one that would be really helpful too.

Comment: Does it need to be a string because you are using string functions to test if it's a palindrome?

Comment: Yeah the base conversion function outputs a string which I was then going to test from the outside>in for palindromicity. I'm only a few weeks into my first programming class so I don't really know how to do complicated algorithms like recursion etc.

Comment: For testing for palindromes, there's no requirement for the digits to be represented as a character. Just keep each digit as an integer.

Comment: But for example 170 to base 16 is AA. So to test to see if this is a palindrome doesn't it need to be a string? if I made it say, 170(base16) = 1010 then the palindrome check wouldn't work.

Comment: You can ask, "Is this an array a palindromic array?" and define "palindromic array" in the obvious way.

Comment: honestly I was trying to manage to do this without using arrays because I haven't really used arrays yet and have no idea what to do if I don't know what size to preallocate them to initially, but I guess I should try to figure out how to do it with arrays instead of string.

Comment: C++ strings are just fancy char arrays with additional magic (e.g. the ability to change size). And `char` is just an 8-bit signed int type that gets special treatment by print and such. Is this a homework problem? Are you sure you need the higher bases?

Comment: It's a class assignment, but we're allowed to use whatever resources we need to to figure it out. The higher bases definitely need to work all the way up to where base < num, because when the base is higher than the number it's always a palindrome. I have a reference executable to see that it's supposed to work for higher than base 64. For instance if I enter 170 it returns 4,
8,
13,
16,
33,
84,
169

Comment: You can use the "strings are just char arrays" and use the string to store the digits (as ints), and pass the string to a function as needed. This will work up until base 127 or 256, depending on how you use it. You shouldn't be printing this string, though, since you're abusing it to store numbers rather than printable characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the program does not actually have to display the converted number to find a palindrome, it can internally represent each "digit" as an `int` (in an array) which is 32 or 64 bits.  This will naturally be fast since such matches are presumably uncommon if not rare.

Once a palindrome match is found, then outputting it can be done anyway you want.  Maybe just print a list of  `int` values.  Look at the [history of hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal#Early_written_representations):  in the early days there were all kinds of unusual schemes, some of which used special characters.

Up to base 64 there are some common standards, but beyond that, you are in largely uncharted territory.

Comment: Thanks, can I output this integer array to another function to test if it's a palindrome or since it's an array do I have to check within that same function?

Answer (score 1):

The standard way, for bases up to 36, is what you said: use more and more letters.

In this case, why not just use spaces as delimiters, or commas? Have each digit be represented by a decimal integer. It'll be more readable than coming up with forty-four new symbols.

Comment: Is there no standard way to convert the example I used 170 to base 90? I read that people start using lowercase from base 36 to base 64, but is there any standard way of doing it after that?

Comment: You can look up some standard ways of doing it. Base 64 has a common way. Consider whether you should, though. The point of output is to be read, and unless you're feeding it to another program, the one reading it will probably be a human.

Comment: I thought I should convert the number to standard form of each base first and then check to see if each string is a palindrome, but I guess since past base 64 doesn't really have a standard I'm going to have to use arrays and check the indexes

Comment: If it's just a thing to pass around within your own program, you can do almost everything with arrays that you can with strings, except know their length (needs to be kept track of with a separate variable).

Comment: can I pass an entire array to another function to do the palindrome check though?

Comment: Yes. You would also need to pass the size, since it isn't part of the array itself. (Rather, you don't pass an array itself, but you can pass a pointer to the array, and a size.)